# Using Mailkit to download email from google as plain/text broke line every 78(maybe) character

Tags: gmail, imap, mailkit

I'm making an project working with gmail. Basically i need to download the mail content and for this i'm using Mailkit.
But by saving email text the final result give me line breaks after some characters.

I google it so i know that is intenet feature using RFC2822.

This is the code i use to download the email to a txt file.

```
var items = client.Inbox.Fetch(0, -1, MessageSummaryItems.UniqueId | MessageSummaryItems.BodyStructure);

foreach (var item in items)
{
    if (item.TextBody != null)
    {
    var mime =(TextPart)client.Inbox.GetBodyPart(item.UniqueId,item.TextBody);
    var text = mime.Text;
    File.WriteAllText("textTest.txt", text);
    }
}
```

Is there any way to continue line instead of break it ? Or i just look the problem from the wrong way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line wrapping is done by either the sender or his mail client. It is not done by MailKit's ImapClient.

Comment: After some research i got that gmail insert new line after 72 characters if you choose that text is plain in options. If i toggle that off i can send full lenght text on another email and on that email i can see same full lenght text, but if i download same email with Mailkit there are new line breaks that make no sense.

Comment: If it's HTML, it's probably in Quoted-Printable encoding; you may need to undo that (or get the library to...)

Comment: If he's using the .Text property, then it is already decoding it. But keep in mind that HTML is not interpreted the same as plain text as far as line breaks go. Line breaks in HTML are ignored.

Comment: I solved the problem by getting the HTML body, idk why before i tryed to get it but every time the folder was empty. So now is working, i'm getting right the html that is what i need. Thank you!